# Uneven distribution of nodes by ToElementMesh[]

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

We are using FEM package to generate mesh in a circular sector. Somehow mesh becomes dense in upper right corner. Is there any way to circumvent this uneven distribution?

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
circularSector = 
  ToElementMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002];
p1 = circularSector["Wireframe"]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Sincerely,

Takashi Miura.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be version dependent; I cannot reproduce this with version 11.3 for macOS.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That probably was a bug / shortcoming that is fixed in Version 11.3

```
$Version
"11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

<< NDSolve`FEM`
circularSector = 
  ToElementMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/4, 3 Pi/4}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.002];
p1 = circularSector["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: It turned out that my student is using older version. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TakashiMiura, you are most welcome. If you or your students have interesting application examples, I am always looking for those to add them to the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns). See in the FEMAddOns Application folder.